# SQL Geography Fast Nearest-neighbor with order by distance

Tags: sql-server-2008, geography

I need to pull a list of addresses based on a current location and within a certain radius. Our default search allows for a 25 mile radius, and with other options, returns around 5400 results. We have stored the addresses as geography points and have created a pretty decent search but the query takes around 3ish seconds to run. Looking over the execution plan I see that the sort takes the most amount of time, which makes sense. What can I do to speed this up? We don't care that it is super exact, so close enough and estimations are ok. The query we are using is below minus most of the other filtering and paging logic.

```
declare @currentLatitude float, @CurrentLongitude float
declare @currentPosition geography
declare @radiusBuffer geography
Set @radiusBuffer = @currentPosition.BufferWithTolerance(10 * 1609.344,.9,1);
set @CurrentLatitude = 39.340579
set @CurrentLongitude = -86.697479
SET @currentPosition = geography::Point(@CurrentLatitude, @CurrentLongitude, 4326);

SELECT a.*,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rt.Position.STDistance(@currentPosition) ASC) AS RowNum
 from    [Address] a 
   where a.Position.Filter(@radiusBuffer) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "WHERE a.Position.STDistance(@currentPosition) < 16093.44", force spatial index with query hint and use "ORDER BY a.Position.STDistance(@currentPosition)" instead of ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: But I use the row_number to do paging, without it it kind of defeats the purpose of the stored proc (Yes i know i can use a temp table to fake it out).

Comment: You must use Order By for that query. Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929109.aspx

Comment: You linked to an article that was only relevant for SQL 2012, I am using 2008.